# Is it considered caught if the ball hits the handle of the bat and is caught?

Tags: rules, cricket

Is it considered caught out if the cricket ball hits the handle of the bat and nothing else and the ball is subsequently caught?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Quoting [Law 33.1](https://www.lords.org/mcc/the-laws-of-cricket/caught):

> The striker is out Caught if a ball delivered by the bowler [...] touches his/her bat and is subsequently held by a fielder [...] before it touches the ground.

The handle is explicitly part of the bat, as defined by [Law 5.1.1](https://www.lords.org/mcc/the-laws-of-cricket/the-bat):

> The bat consists of two parts, a handle and a blade.